# looking for a better solution to modify background parent when child div is hovered with css or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, parent-child

i try to modify a background div when i hover a child div. Please notice that i have more than one child and here is my solution.

But i'm pretty sure that there is a better way to achieve that who will of course be visible by all navigators (I.E, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome...) That's why i didn't use the has() option !!

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/oh1u2nvq/#save)

```
<h2 class="wl-bg-collectif">
<span class="w-text-block" style="display: block;">
<span class="w-text-content">ONE</span>
</span>
</h2>

<h2 class="wl-bg-prive">
<span class="w-text-block" style="display: block;">
<span class="w-text-content">TWO</span>
</span>
</h2>

<h2 class="wl-bg-live">
<span class="w-text-block" style="display: block;">
<span class="w-text-content">THREE</span>
</span>
</h2>
```

```
.w-text-content {
padding-bottom: 600px!important;
margin-bottom: -600px!important;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.wl-bg-collectif .w-text-content:hover {
background: transparent url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636f04c51f4f1b000d196c8c) no-repeat right top!important;
background-size: 50%!important;
z-index: -1;
color: #F24908!important;
}

.wl-bg-prive .w-text-content:hover {
background: transparent url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636f04c51f4f1b000d196c8c) no-repeat right top!important;
background-size: 50%!important;
z-index: -1;
color: #F24908!important;
}

.wl-bg-live .w-text-content:hover {
background: transparent url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636f04c51f4f1b000d196c8c) no-repeat right top!important;
background-size: 50%!important;
z-index: -1;
color: #F24908!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I tried to explain to you in my comments:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const wl_img = document.getElementById('wl-img');

  [
    ['collectif', 'https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636e7ce48b2d53000d9af524'],
    ['prive', 'https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636e7ce26da50f000c512a26'],
    ['live', 'https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636f04c51f4f1b000d196c8c']
  ].forEach(([className, url]) => {
    const el = document.querySelector(`.wl-bg-${ className }`)

    el.onmouseover = () => {
      wl_img.style.display = '';
      wl_img.src = url
    }
    el.onmouseleave = () => {
      wl_img.style.display = 'none';
      wl_img.src = ''
    }
  })
}
```

```css
h2:hover,
h2:focus,
h2:active {
  color: #F24908 !important;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#wl-img {
  height: 20%;
  max-height: 50em;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="w-section__footer">

  <div>
    <h2 class="wl-bg-collectif">COLLECTIF</h2>
    <h2 class="wl-bg-prive text_1k0">PRIVÉ</h2>
    <h2 class="wl-bg-live text_1k0">LIVE ONLINE</h2>
  </div>

  <img id="wl-img" style="display: none">

</footer>
```

Comment: ah sorry I understand it better now, thanks a lot, last thing, did you know why we can't see background images fullheight ?

Comment: totally, i had to say yes !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in css `:has` pseudo element like this :

```css
.wl-bg * {
  padding-bottom: 600px !important;
  margin-bottom: -600px !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: fit-content;
}

.wl-bg:has(:hover) {
  background: transparent url(https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636f04c51f4f1b000d196c8c) no-repeat right top!important;
  background-size: 50% !important;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #F24908 !important;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="wl-bg wl-bg-collectif">
  <span>ONE</span>
</h2>

<h2 class="wl-bg wl-bg-prive">
  <span>TWO</span>
</h2>

<h2 class="wl-bg wl-bg-live">
  <span>THREE</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: but do you think that has() it's necessary here if the .wl-bg * {} is used for navigators who can't read it ?  I mean why don"t use .wl-bg * {} directly for all navigators ? 

In a second time, i think that this option is less clean that has() but it works everywhere

Comment: I don’t really understand your question but there the ".wl-bg:has(:hover)" means "select every element with the wl-bg class which has one of its children hovered"
If it doesn’t answer your question, please ask it again another way

Comment: sorry, let me explain it better, first of all, please note that the background image is different for the each child <h2>, then the has() option does not work on Firefox for example !! I would like to know one simple solution to achieve what I want with a smart and not so much css or javascript who will work with all navigators and versions without using hack like "padding-bottom: 600px !important; margin-bottom: -600px !important;"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is by using a little bit of `js` like so :

```js
window.onload = () => Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic-hover-bg') ).forEach(div => Array.from( div.children ).forEach(e => {
        e.onmouseover  = () => div.style.backgroundImage = `url(${ e.dataset.bgUrl })`
        e.onmouseleave = () => div.style.backgroundImage = ''
    })
)
```

```css
.wl-bg span:hover {
    color: #F24908 !important;
}

.wl-bg {
    width: fit-content;
}

.dynamic-hover-bg {
    background-size: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="dynamic-hover-bg">
  <h2 class="wl-bg wl-bg-collectif" data-bg-url="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/a2hkMAaruSQ8haQZ4rBL9/8ff4a6f289b9ca3f4e6474f29793a74a/nature-image-for-website.jpg">
    <span>ONE</span>
  </h2>
  
  <h2 class="wl-bg wl-bg-prive" data-bg-url="https://cdn.futura-sciences.com/sources/images/dossier/773/01-intro-773.jpg">
    <span>TWO</span>
  </h2>
  
  <h2 class="wl-bg wl-bg-live" data-bg-url="https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636f04c51f4f1b000d196c8c">
    <span>THREE</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Hope it helped you !

Comment: Hi can you check what i've done with your solution, it looks like it does not work ? https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/Lpv5hf0z/9/

Comment: There are two problems in your fiddle :
- First, you footer doesn't have the "w-section__footer" class
- Second, you used string interpolation inside a simple string ('sting') but it only works on templates strings (`string ${ var }`)

And, as an improve, you can store your urls in an array like so :
(not enough chars remaining so the next com)

Comment: [
    [ 'collectif', 'https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636e7ce48b2d53000d9af524' ],
    [ 'prive', 'https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636e7ce26da50f000c512a26' ],
    [ 'live', 'https://res2.yourwebsite.life/res/5ef668f5db29eb0022cd0cd6/636f04c51f4f1b000d196c8c' ]
].forEach(([ className, url ]) => document.querySelector(`.wl-bg-${ className }`).dataset.bgUrl = url)

Comment: you right about the error N°1, then for the N°2 i don't really get it !! if i modify my jsfiddle but don't know how to use your part of code : https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/Lpv5hf0z/25/